# Fully featured file download manager for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, download, file-manager

I've been looking for a nice file download manager I can use in my app and haven't been able to find anything with the features I want...

- queue multiple async downloads
- control number of simultaneous downloads
- block based callbacks include success, fail and progress percentage updates
- cancel and pause/resume
- resume interrupted downloads (e.g. when the app is force closed)

the following would be nice bonuses

- remaining time estimation
- ability to change order in queue
- handling of long term storage/deletion

Does anyone know of anything like this? If there's nothing out there I guess I can roll my own and open source it.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you finally use an existing framework or create your own? Thanks for sharing your experience...

Comment: Hi Phil, I created my own in the end. I'd love to open source it some time, but it would need some more work and I'm super busy right now. If I ever get around to it I'll post back here and let you know.

Comment: Hi Marky, I'm going to create my own as I need something similar for downloads and uploads on my current project. Could be a good idea to create a common open source project based on what you have, please contact me through my website if you are interested.

Comment: @Marky : Hi.. 
U did the above functionality that u mention in your question?  Pls share your demo with me

Answer (score 2):

[Here's mine.](https://github.com/H2CO3/HCDownload) Although the callbacks are delegate-based rathrer than block-based, you can easily adapt this. You can also easily add code to limit number of parallel downloads by examining the number of current downloads and only adding a new if it's less than the limit. It also has remaining time estimation and nicely formatts data sizes. Using NSFileHandle, it doesn't eat up your memory, instead it writes to files directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it's not quite what I'm looking for as it seems to be tightly coupled to a view controller, which I don't need. I'm looking more for a singleton manager type thing. But thanks for open sourcing your code :)

Comment: @Marky I see. Perhaps I should have separated it from the UI... But nevertheless, you can instantiate a view controller without displaying it. You can also fork my repo, delete the UI-related code from the classes and use it as a subclass of NSObject...

Comment: you are using ViewController as a method parameter, i think that it's not a good design.

Comment: @samir What? Ever used `UITableView` or any class working with delegates? 1. Why do you think it's bad? 2. If the view controller is not passed as an argument, there's no way the delegate can determine which instance called it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for the same thing. I haven't tried it yet, but this one seems promising:

https://github.com/robertmryan/download-manager

Comment: This demo is very useful but how can I implement stop and resume download file. Pls help me

Comment: @MonikaPatel Did you implemented this stop and resume?

Comment: @MonikaPatel Yes. But, i've used in different way based on my requirement.

Comment: @MonikaPatel See, you can write your own download manager based on your requirement. But, i would like to suggest you to use `NSURLSession` instead `NSURLConnection` Because, `NSURLSession` has powerful mechanism which has more additional implemented methods.

Comment: @MonikaPatel See, you can also start doing exactly like [this tutorial.](http://www.appcoda.com/background-transfer-service-ios7/) I've created a model where downloads processing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117564/discussion-between-monika-patel-and-praveen).